# Sympy functions with indices as variables

Tags: sympy

I would like to create a new class of function in sympy where :

```
f=new_class_function(r"f")(l,m,theta)
sy.print_latex(f)
f_{l,m}\left( \theta , \phi \right)
```

And the idea will be that this class is working for whatever function not only one.
I know to do it for one from this previous post :
[Create indexed functions in sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70501060/create-indexed-functions-in-sympy)

It will be nice if the l,m act like indices that is to say sy.Derivative(f,theta) gives a d/dtheta and not a delta/delta theta

Thanks for your help :)